# Navegacion entre paginas

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

estoy haciendo una aplicación Android con Xamarin, en la app tengo 2 páginas una que es la página login(usuario, contraseña y un boton ingresar), que cuando presiono ese botón, me lleva a la segunda página que sería la página del menú. Cuando quiero volver hacia atrás(pantalla login) me repite 2 veces la página menú y vuelve al login, no encuentro una solución a ese error. ¿Me podrian ayudar?

Así llamo a la página :

```
this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new menu());
```

Comment: Hola @BraianWegner, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Bienvenido BrianWenger a StackOverflow En Español. Colocar una sola línea de código ayuda muy poco, sería más mejor si editas tu pregunta y agregas las vistas seguido del código que estás usando, de esta manera tendrías una mejor respuesta y motivarías a más usuarios a darte una porque las preguntas bien redactadas tienen mayor chance de ser resueltas. Saludos :D